# R add legend for multiple layers

Tags: r, addition, legend

I want to add a legend for the plot, but it doesn't work,
can anyone please help me to see where it went wrong.

this is the code.

```html
ggplot(data = dfNorm1, aes(x = X)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Government_suppliment), 
           fill = "#0000FF", color = "white", alpha = 0.8) + 
  geom_smooth(data = subset(dfNorm1,X >= 24), aes(y = Government_suppliment),
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#FF4040", 
              linetype = "dashed", size = 0.7) + 
  geom_smooth(data = subset(dfNorm1, X <= 24), aes(y = Government_suppliment),
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#FF4040", 
              linetype = "dashed", size = 0.7) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 24.5, size = 0.8, alpha = 0.8) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Poverty_funds), 
            color = "#FF0000", size = 1, alpha = 0.7) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = MLI), color = "#EF3EFF", size = 1, 
            alpha = 0.8) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "",values = c("bar.label" = "#0000FF")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("line.label1" = "#FF0000", "line.label2" = "#EF3EFF",
                                           "line.labeld" = "#FF4040"))
```

Comment: There's no need to call multiple geoms(e.g geom_line twice). If you find yourself doing so, it might be time to reshape your data and/or make separate plots.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more reproducible by using `dput` to add sample data.

Comment: okay, thanks, I will reshape it again

Answer (score 0):

You usually can produce a legend by setting `aes(color = column_title)` in one of your geom layers. This code doesn't particularly make sense because you are referencing more than one y-axis without creating a second y-axis (a bad habit if you are trying to do so). Is there a way you can post more relevant code or a reproducible example so people can see exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps better as a comment.

Comment: It keeps telling me I don't have enough karma for comments so I figured I would post as an answer to help out anyway. I felt the same way though.

Comment: I hope it doesn't get flagged for removal. If OP edits their question, then you can better rephrase it as an answer and/or delete it if you find you can't answer anymore. Cheers!

Comment: okay, thank you very much, I should have posted the plot, but my level too low to do so.